# Serialize error from user control

Tags: c#

I have created a user control (CheckedDirTree) that exposes a CheckedFolder property which in turn returns an IEnumerable of the FullPath property of Nodes checked in the control. Something like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<string> CheckedFolders
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes[0].DescendantNodes())
            {
                if(node.Checked && !node.FullPath.Equals(_directoryRoot))
                    yield return node.FullPath;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is being fed to another class's (SymbolsShareDto) Folders property after this cntrol is shown in a grid and the user has checked some folders:

```
using (var dirControl = new CheckedDirForm(symbolsShare))
                {
                    if (dirControl.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        var symbolsShareObj = bindingSourceShare.Current as SymbolShareModel;
                        if (symbolsShareObj != null) symbolsShareObj.Folders = dirControl.CheckedFolders;
                    }
                }

[DataContract]
public class SymbolShareDTO
{
    public SymbolShareDTO(){}

    [DataMember]
    public string Share { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string BackupTo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Folders { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Share: {0}{1}BackupTo: {2}{3}Folders: {4}", Share, Environment.NewLine, BackupTo,
                             Environment.NewLine, Folders.Count());
    }
}
```

However when I serialize the SymbolsShareDto, I'm getting an error saying

```
CheckedDirTree+<get_CheckedFolders>d__6' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
```

Any thoughts ? Do I need to return a new List from CheckedFolders property instead.

thanks
Sunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `CheckedFolders.ToArray()` and serialize that.

Comment: That worked fine. Is there any pros/cons with doing ToArray or ToList ?

Comment: Nope, not really. An array will be more compact when serialized though.

Answer (score 0):

use
`[DataContract]` for your class ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx))

and  `[DataMember]` for each property ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28VS.85%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to send instances of SymbolsShareDto through WCF.

All you have to do is to mark it with DataContractAttribute and all the property with DataMember :

```
[DataContract]
public class SymbolsShareDto 
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Data1 { get; set;};

     [DataMember]
     public int Data2 { get; set;}
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I already have the DTO marked for using DataContractSerializer. See my edits.